# Using angular and backbone in the same app

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js

I am working on a backbone app that we want to migrate over to angular. However, a true "port" or "rewrite" is not an option due to resource constraints. Instead, we want to introduce angular into the app in a modular sort of way -- ie, identify and carve off easily separatable functionality and make it angular, as well as introduce any new modules (i.e. an admin module) as angular code.

Is this possible? If so: a) Where would you put your "ng-view" tag? Inside the div that you currently render your backbone-based markup? b) How do you introduce angular-routes into all of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add **target="_self"** for all the backbone links, then angular would not route those links. We had the same problem and adding this fixed the problem. Hope this helps..

```
<a href="/test" target="_self">Test</a>
```

Comment: This seems to do the magic. Just wondering what prompted you to try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular in any place you want in your app and use it with backbone if you want but stay in mind that you're using two frameworks and in this case it's totally unnecessary and wrong, but i think that you don't have choice, all you have todo is put the directive "ng-app" where you want to use angular, here is my example:

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
 //your code here
</html>
```

and the script(like any other angularjs app):

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);
// the rest of the code
```

I never tested before angularjs + backbone, but i think you can have some problems like to deal with data from server, who will gonna do that? Angular or Backbone?

Comment: Okay, but how do I have angular routes handle angular stuff, and still have backbone routes work? Do I make angular routes control everything, and just call backbone routes from $routeProvider.when() when I need to?

Comment: I'm not the best person to say it, but i think it's best use only angular when you're dealing with angular stuff and let backbone to deal only with backbone stuff, but this is not scalable because i think you will reach a point that you will want to deal with data from backbone in some angular module, so i think that the best way is to rewrite pieces by pieces from the old stuff write in backbone to angular...

Comment: I agree with you. But I still wonder what the best strategy of re-writing piece by piece in angular is. How do you continue to have the old pieces not yet re-written continue to function alongside the new angular pieces?

In other words, say I want to re-write the "admin" module in angular. Currently there is a backbone route that handles "/admin". How do I successfully carve that off and write it in angular, and not have the backbone router handle it anymore?

Comment: It depends on how you wrote your code, i'm not able to tell you how you would do that without looking your code... I think the best approach is piece by piece, module by module, and if you have other backbone modules that depends from a module that you rewrite to angular, you just keeps this old backbone module until you have those others modules also rewritten, yes your code will gonna get ugly and duplicate, but it's temporary.